# How To Use Angular HttpParams And SQL JOIN With Get Request?

Tags: angular

My first use of REST and the Angular docs for HttpParams are useless for learning, at least for me.  Also, there are only a few older SO questions and none cover joins, or the approach we are supposed to be taking after an update on Sept 9, 2017.  So I, and probably many others, need some guidance please :-)

This url string works fine but is really ugly:

```
return this.http
        .get<DfApi>(this.baseUrl + dbTable + '?filter=' + '('
          + column1 + '%20like%20' + entry + '%25)%20or%20('
          + column2 + '%20like%20' + entry + '%25)', {headers: this.headers});
```

I know I can use string interpolation but for me, a newbie, the above is easier to visualize. I understand that "let params = new HttpParams().set...;" isn't used since early September, 2017.  So something like this is needed to set the params.

```
this.params = {
        // do something
      };
```

I believe I want to get to this:

```
return this.http
        .get<DfApi>(`${this.baseUrl}/${dbTable}`, 
                    {params: this.params, headers: this.headers});
```

I have no idea how to get from my url string to setting parameters that result in a url string.  I'm surprised there are no blog posts on this yet because it seems like it should be taught somewhere.

By the way, my headers for Postgres use the old method.

Comment: Parameters are key value pairs. Angular doesn't care what the value of the parameter is. It must be a string, that's all.

Comment: "easier to visualize" lol!

Comment: I don't see key value pairs in this url string.  I know how to send JSON back and forth.  This is a query.  It probably is easy if you already have a clue...

Comment: The key value pair is `this.params = {filter: 'your_sql_string'};` from here angular will take care of transforming it to a query string `filter=your_sql_string`. Sending an SQL statement from the client seems like a security risk

Comment: Like this?  But it doesn't accept vars.   this.params = {
        'filter': '${column1} like ${entry}'
      };

Comment: For ${} to be interpolated, the string must be surrounded by backticks, not simple quotes.

Comment: Thank you JB Nizet and LLai!  I'll post my code as the answer. It looks so easy now but when you start from clueless about REST the concept isn't there yet.

Answer (score 0):

My code with two different searches, the first one queries two database columns (fields) and the second only one column.  This works fine for development but has security concerns for production.

```
public search(dbTable: string, column1: string, column2: string, entry: string) {

    if (column1 === 'main_skill1') {

      this.params = {
        'filter': `(${column1} like ${entry}%) or (${column2} like ${entry}%)`
      };

      return this.http
        .get<DfApi>(`${this.baseUrl}${dbTable}?`, {params: this.params, headers: this.headers});

    } else {

      this.params = {
        'filter': `(${column1} like ${entry}%)`
      };

      return this.http
        .get<DfApi>(`${this.baseUrl}${dbTable}?`, {params: this.params, headers: this.headers});

    }
```